# Ruby on Rails - can't store an array of hashes in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am creating an array of hashes and passing it into a controller via json. Here is the data that I am sending and some server output right before it:

```
Started POST "/api/user.json" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Jun 27 18:52:32 -0400 2012
  Processing by Api::UsersController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"accept"=>"json", "content_type"=>"json", "users"=>"[{\"email\":\"kirsten_gronberg@yahoo.com\"},{\"email\":\"dtsheahan@msn.com\"},{\"email\":\"clayton19361@hotmail.com\"},{\"email\":\"kumar.alka92@yahoo.com\"},{\"email\":\"j.eromes.n.d.c@gmail.com\\r\"},{\"email\":\"0\"},{\"email\":\"christine@colormepink.com\"},{\"email\":\"janabouc@gmail.com\"},{\"email\":\"carin@inkfoundry.com\"},{\"email\":\"jon.neiditz@nelsonmullins.com\"}]"}
```

here is my controller code:

params["users"].each { |user_params|
  User.create!(user_params)
}

and here is the error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `keys' for #<String:0x10662d660>):
  app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb:6:in `create'
  app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb:5:in `each'
  app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb:5:in `create'
```

Would anyone have any idea what might be happening wrong for me here?

Thanks!

Comment: How does a user_param look like when inspected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you receive `params[:users]`, you are in fact receiving a string and not a hash. This string just happens to be encoded in JSON (i.e. in a style carrying the likeness of a Ruby hash.) You must convert this string into your hash through a method such as `hash = JSON.parse(params[:users])`.